# Is the CrossValidated impact "people reached" formula generally available?

Tags: discussion, reputation

This may be proprietary, but does someone know how they translate page views of questions and "highly ranked" (what does this mean?) answers into 'impact'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ["People reached"  stat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534) is the sum of views on the following:

> - **Questions**
>
>   - Non-deleted only
> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count